# How to make SMB mounted volume act like a local volume?

Tags: network, spotlight, mount, smb

The question is vague and also suggests exactly what I have been trying to do for over a month now. I moved a few external enclosures to a Mac Mini "server" and am connecting to them over ethernet from my client iMac.

I find that the privileges aren't the same when those volumes are mounted (SMB doesn't mount drives with the same privileges as on the server) and I want them to be since I am the only user accessing them.

There are non-GUI adjustable settings for SMB volumes via Terminal. I am not clear on those options and from which side to set those options for each volume, server or client.

I find that Spotlight can't search all files on the mounted volumes (some text files are found and, for instance, movie files are not).

**regarding mounting smb volume with `rwx` privileges for "everyone"**

I set the umask to 0777 for the drives on the client iMac and that made no difference.
I set ACL's on the server side and of course that doesn't matter when the client mounts the volume.
I have set "ignore ownership" on the remote volumes.

I have read about adding or editing the smb.conf file... not sure where to start with that (client or server). I assume the client? And need help with what commands work today and not 15 years ago.

**regarding spotlight**

I have rebuilt the index on the server side for all volumes.

I thought this might help but really don't know what network stores store 
`defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores -bool FALSE`

Playing around with `smbutil` command I found I can't run this command successfully:

```
13:07:20.194 at iMac191 ~ smbutil view smb://mac-mini.local
Password for mac-mini.local: 
smbutil: server rejected the authentication: Authentication error
```

However the same password works for this command:

```
13:24:01.186 at iMac191 ~ smbutil dfs smb://mac-mini.local
Password for mac-mini.local: 

No server entries found

No referral entries found
```

I am really just grabbing at straws and realize it. That's why I am posting here.